# Slope analysis where one group is not normally distributed

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, p-value, dataset

I am currently doing analysis of five separate drug groups and their changes in levels of prescription over time. Having done linear regression on excel I am comparing the 'steepness' (m) of the slopes to eachother to ascertain whether or not one has significantly increased compared to another. I am using this equation:

[image: Equation]

I have three questions:

1) Is this the best way of comparing 'is one group of drugs increasing more than the other?' I thought about using a 'dummy line' where it is completely flat (showing no change) and comparing them all to that except a flat line has no m value to put into the equation!

2) One group of drugs appears to be not normally distributed (oxycodone) - even though the graph seems to show a relatively straight line increase - am I still able to analyze this group using the stats test shown above?

3) How can I convert a Z-score to a P-value?

The data is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Bumping thread to get an answer!